# String length limit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, string-length, maxstringcontentlength

I'm doing an app for Android using Java and Eclipse. I did some research and apparently there is no limit in Java for how long the strings can be. 
So, I set up my database with a single string containing some 40000-50000 characters and it worked really well (Eclipse to Samsung Galaxy S3). Then I got an issue with updating Eclipse and therefore I decided to continue programming with this new "Android Studio" instead. Everything works fine except I get this Error(at line) java: constant string too long.
Is there a max limit for string lengths in Android Studio but not in Eclipse? Is there somehow I can set the preferences so Android Studio accepts these long strings ?

Comment: This is the same question with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222893/max-length-of-a-string-variable-in-android

Comment: No, the project compiled fine with Eclipse but not with Android Studio. There must be an issue with long strings in Android Studio. The answer in that article doesn't help me.